# Unable to run a C# .exe using sp_cmdshell stored procedure

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, xp-cmdshell

I want to run a Selenium C# `.exe` using a SQL job. But its throwing an error

> The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0xF389F41117ABC54D9DDB8DF613345572 (reason: The parameter is incorrect).  The step failed.
>
> Executed Command : EXEC master..xp_cmdshell '\serverName\H$\Debug\Selenium "\serverName\D$\SeleniumDriverLocation" "OneExcelFileLocation" "IntegerValue"'

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code you are running please, without it, we are flying blind here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arran..But i didn't get your point, which code you want me to share. I am simply executing the .exe by passing some parameters to it, which is failing. So probably something is wrong the way I am passing the parameters or something else.

Comment: So we'll need to see where you read the parameters.

Comment: Reading main parameters: if(args.length > 0) {var1 = args[0]; var 2 = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]...}. But my point is I dun think that system is even able to reach till this point of executing the code because error says the process creation step fails. Please do correct me if i am wrong.